# Make one or several columns in a list (type: multiple lines) expandable / collapsable in Sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2013, column

I struggle to make 2 columns within a list (which are set to multiple lines as they do contain quite some characters that make the list itself very hard to browse) to be minimized/shortened by default and expandable upon clicking to show all of the text.

I found some scripts for SP 2010 and [one of them adapted to SP2013](https://myofficeworkonsharepoint.wordpress.com/2017/04/08/sharepoint-2013-script-for-collapse-the-text-in-multi-line-text-column-in-sharepoint-list/), but it is not not working for me.

Can someone help me to realise my request within Sharepoint 2013 without using the SP Designer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use some CSS in a script editor web part on the same page where the list is.

If you want it to expand on click, you can change `:hover` to `:focus`.

```
<style type="text/css">
.ms-vb2 .ms-rtestate-field:hover {
    max-height: none;
}
.ms-vb2 .ms-rtestate-field {
    max-width: 250px;
    max-height: 38px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
</style>
```

**Update**

To keep a field expanded until the next is clicked, you could do it with Jquery instead.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(window).bind('hashchange', function() {
truncateMultiRow(); 
});

_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("truncateMultiRow");

    function truncateMultiRow() {
        $(".ms-rtestate-field").after( "<span class=readMore><p>Click to read more</p></span>" );
        $("table.ms-listviewtable > tbody > tr").click(function() {
        $(".ms-rtestate-field").css('max-height', '38px');
        $(this).find(".ms-rtestate-field").css('max-height', 'none');   
        })
    }
</script>
<style type="text/css">
.ms-vb2 .ms-rtestate-field {
    max-width: 250px;
    max-height: 38px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.readMore {
    color: #3498db;
    cursor: pointer;
}
</style>
```

So, when one of the multiple lines of text field is click, it will expand, and if you click another, the first one closes and the one clicked will expand instead.

The jQuery is from a CDN, while it works good, you can download the jquery library and add to your site and then refer it locally.

> The integrity and crossorigin attributes are used for Subresource
>   Integrity (SRI) checking. This allows browsers to ensure that
>   resources hosted on third-party servers have not been tampered with.
>   Use of SRI is recommended as a best-practice, whenever libraries are
>   loaded from a third-party source.

[jQuery.com](http://jquery.com/download/)

Comment: Dear Christoffer,
thank you very much for your most helpful comment, this is working really great with the "focus" command in your script. Is there a way to keep the text expanded after a click and collapse it after another? At the moment it stays expanded as long as I hold down the mouse button on the item.

Comment: Like, expand one, click on another and expand that one instead and close the other?

Comment: @user68489 see my updated answer

Comment: We are approaching the perfect solution for me. Yes, the Javascript behaves nearly as I wanted it to. I hope I am not asking for too much as I already appreciate your support to this point, but would it be possible that it does not matter where in the respective Sharepoint-List-Entry I am clicking? At the moment I have to target the area where the multiple lines are hidden. If you do not know there is more text, I guess noone would click there.

Additionally, is it possible to automatically write like "[Read more]" at the end of the abbreviated, collapsed text so one knows there is more text

Comment: @user68489 I'l look into it to expand on row click and get back!

Comment: @user68489 Updated the code, just copy it and it should work when clicking on the list item row!

Comment: Unfortunately, with the updated code it just truncates but does not expand no matter where I click :(

Comment: @user68489 my bad, pasted the wrong code from one of my sheets instead of the working one, please try again

Comment: Nice job Christoffer, with the updated code it does exactly what I wanted it to!

Lastly, is there a possibility to mark areas where more text is hidden to allow viewers to easily identify respective areas, such as auto display [...more] at the end of the truncated text or give a grahical hint somehow? Would be the last thing I ask you, because then it would be perfect.

Comment: @user68489 There is no easy way to add a "read more" sign after some of the text, however what i could do is inserting a text saying "Click to read more" instead of the actual text..

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/sLL9Q

Comment: If I understood you correctly, you could create a code that changes the displayed text of a truncated list item automatically to e.g. "Click to read more" if it is a multiline field? Or do you mean I should enter that manually in the beginning of each line (would also be a way to achieve what I want, correct. But the list I am editing is huge, so if there is an easy way achieving this by code, that would be great). If that won't be much work for you I would appreciate if you could give that a try.

Comment: @user68489 yeah, either that or below the text that is truncated. See the image here: http://imgur.com/a/frKhi

Comment: Thanks for your support Christoffer, you really helped me alot!

Comment: @user68489 updated with some extras.

Comment: Just came around a bug: When performing a search (standard SP search box feature) in the collapsed list, the search does display the correct list entry in abbreviated format - but then the expand on click does not work any more until I reload the page. Is there a workaround for that issue? I guess its not specific to your code

Comment: Awesome. "Click to read more" works like a charm, that is now exactly (!) what I was looking for.

Comment: @user68489 ah, SharePoint search uses Ajax to reload the table and showing the search results, meaning that the actual table is reloaded and not the page so the inserted code is being removed.. guess you could tinker with the searchbox and find when the search icon/or enter i pressed and then reload the whole page but that would be a kind of ugly way to do it..

Comment: Appreciate your feedback regarding the bug. Many thanks for your continuous support on this!

Comment: @user68489 Think i managed to solve it, i noticed that the jquery where removed when using filters aswell. See my updated code.

Comment: Solved it. To 100%. Genius!

Comment: @user68489 I'm afraid not, as removing the search or searching again voids it.. but you might be able to live with it?

Comment: I think I (have to and) can live with that :-)

Comment: @user68489 haha, back to my work then! :)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61936/discussion-on-answer-by-christoffer-make-one-or-several-columns-in-a-list-type).